# Algorithm to sort three kinds of balls

Tags: algorithm, sorting

We have N balls of three different types: red(r), blue(b), and white(w).

I need to sort them so that red balls appear firsts, then all white balls and finally all blue balls.

Example:

In: bwrwrbbrwwrb

```
string[] arrBalls = { "b", "w", "r", "w", "r", "b", "b", "r", "w", "w", "r", "b" };
```

Out:rrrrwwwwbbbb

I need to found a linear O(n) algorithm.

**Update:** C# code

```
 string[] arrBalls = { "b", "w", "r", "w", "r", "b", "b", "r", "w", "w", "r", "b" };
 int index_red = 0;
 int index_blue = arrBalls.Length - 1;

 for (int i = 0; i < arrBalls.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arrBalls[i] == "r" && index_red != i)
                {
                    string TempRed = arrBalls[index_red];
                    arrBalls[index_red] = arrBalls[i];
                    arrBalls[i] = TempRed;
                    if (arrBalls[index_red] == "r")
                    {
                        while(arrBalls[index_red] == "r")index_red++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        index_red++;
                    }


                }


                if (arrBalls[i] == "b" && index_blue != i)
                {
                    string TempRed = arrBalls[index_blue];
                    arrBalls[index_blue] = arrBalls[i];
                    arrBalls[i] = TempRed;

                    if (arrBalls[index_blue] == "b")
                    {
                        while (arrBalls[index_blue] == "b") index_blue--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        index_blue--;
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: Can you pls add a tag specifying the language you're using?

Comment: Please stick to a formatting convention not wasting vertical space, at least in StackExchange postings. (Depending on language (you don't name one), string comparison using `==` may or may not give the desired result.)

Comment: This is c# code,but i am looking for the best algorithm O(1n), i don't care wich language  to use c++,c#,javascrit.this why i didn't tag any language .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You count each one of the three types of balls into 3 variables. Let's say you counted `R` red balls, `B` blue ones and `W` white ones. Then you output `R "r"`, followed by `W "w"`, followed by `B "b"`.

Comment: You mean to count all types+build new arr=O(2n) ,There is no way to do this with O(1n)?Go over arr ony one time?

Comment: I go over the array once. Then I use only the 3 counters. Also `O(2n) = O(n)`. When using `O` multiplication constants don't matter.

Comment: Yea i know that O(2n)+O(5n)=O(n),i just thought to move all red ball to start and blue to end than all white ball will stay in center here there code see Update, but is your way is better?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, this approach is termed as Postman's Sort in the Wikipedia Article about Bucket Sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Comment: [_Counting sort_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), rather. _Postman's Sort_ would seem appropriate to a _most significant digit[attribute] first_ radix sort.